# Inno Setup and Copying a file

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have an installer that is working just fine. What I would like to do is copy a DLL that is part of the installed application to another folder. For example I am installing the application on E:\Folder, but I would like to copy a DLL from that install to E:\public.

Is it possible to have Inno copy a file to another folder as part of an install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy that library into a folder which is a subfolder of the parent folder selected by the user on the *Select Destination Location* wizard page, then you should specify the path relative to the [`{app}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#app) folder for the [`DestDir`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=DestDir) parameter of your [`[Files]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_filessection.htm) section entry for that library. In script it would be something like this:

```
[Files]
Source: "App.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Library.dll"; DestDir: "{app}\..\Public"
```

Just to make it clear, if the user selects e.g. this folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\App Folder
```

Then the library will be copied to this folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Public
```

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the file from the old installation? I install the app. I install new version, but I need to keep one single file during the installation of the new version. that file is a database which is modified by the user.